# Drop duplicates while preserving NaNs in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

When using the `drop_duplicates()` method I reduce duplicates but also merge all `NaNs` into one entry. How can I drop duplicates while preserving rows with an empty entry (like `np.nan, None or  ''`)?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['one','two',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'two','two']})

Out[]: 
   col
0  one
1  two
2  NaN
3  NaN
4  NaN
5  two
6  two


df.drop_duplicates(['col'])

Out[]: 
   col
0  one
1  two
2  NaN
```

Answer (score 39):

Try

```
df[(~df.duplicated()) | (df['col'].isnull())]
```

The result is :

```
col
0   one
1   two
2   NaN
3   NaN     
4   NaN
```

Comment: for a very large dataset, `df=df[df['col'].isnull() | ~df[df['col'].notnull()].duplicated(subset='col',keep='first')]` turns out faster.

Comment: @user2118915 - If there are duplicate values in the index, you might want to
    `df.reset_index(inplace = True)` beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

Well, one workaround that is not really beautiful is to first save the `NaN` and put them back in:

```
temp = df.iloc[pd.isnull(df).any(1).nonzero()[0]]
asd = df.drop_duplicates('col')
pd.merge(temp, asd, how='outer')
Out[81]: 
   col
0  one
1  two
2  NaN
3  NaN
4  NaN
```

Comment: Note that this only saved  `NaN` and not other versions of "missing". What exactly you save depends on your data set. Typically, it does not make sense to have several different `missing data` indicators at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
df.drop_duplicates('col').append(df[df['col'].isna()])
```