# In pandas how to use drop_duplicates with one exception?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, exception, drop-duplicates

In python 3 and pandas I need to eliminate duplicate rows from a dataframe by repeating values in a column. For this I used:

```
consolidado = df_processos.drop_duplicates(['numero_unico'], keep='last')
```

The column "numero_unico" has codes in string format like 0029126-45.2019.1.00.0000, 0026497-98.2019.1.00.0000, 0027274-83.2019.1.00.0000...

So the above command keeps only the last string code appearance found

Please does anyone know how to use drop_duplicates with one exception?

But the column contents will not always be string codes. In several lines appears the content "Sem número único"

And I want to keep all the lines where this exception exists. But with the above command the generated dataframe keeps only the last appearance of "Sem número único"

Comment: remove the rows that have "Sem número único", do dedup on original df, then merge the "Sem número único" rows back in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example from my comment on the OP,

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'a': ['snu', 'snu', '002', '002', '003', '003'], 
    'b': [1, 2, 2, 1, 5, 6]
})
df_dedupe = pandas.concat([ 
    df[df['a']=='snu'], 
    df[df['a']!='snu'].drop_duplicates(['a'], keep='last') 
])
```

Comment: Good stuff thanks! I'd been trying to get this to work for ages

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the other answers, but in one multi-line command using the duplicated() method:

```
consolidado = df_processos[
    df_processos['numero_unico'] == "Sem número único" |
    ~df_processos[df_processos['numero_unico'] != "Sem número único"].duplicated(
        subset='numero_unico', keep='last'
    )
]
```

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35860429/2740563)

Answer (score 1):

There's no parameter in the pandas `drop_duplicates` you can use, but you can get around it by separating the `DataFrame` into two parts (with "Sem número único" and without), and then concat back together after deduplicating. As so:

```
tmp_df1 = df_processos[df_processos['numero_unico']=="Sem número único"]
tmp_df2 = df_processos[df_processos['numero_unico']!='Sem número único']
tmp_df2 = tmp_df2.drop_duplicates(['numero_unico'], keep='last')
new_df = pd.concat([tmp_df1, tmp_df2])
```