# In Python, remove both duplicates to a new dataframe while ignoring NaN ( empty cells)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a dataframe with duplicates in `Animals`. I want to parse out **both** rows if there is a duplicate in `Animals` into a new df. I'm having issues with the **both** part.

Input df:

```
   Animals   Stuff
0  Cow       red
1  NaN       blue
3  123       green
4  Cow       green
5  NaN       1235
6  Dog       1235
7  123       red
```

Here is my desired output with two dataframes

df1:

```
  Animals   Stuff
1  NaN      blue
5  NaN      1235
6  Dog      1235
```

df2:

```
   Animals   Stuff
0  Cow       red
4  Cow       green
3  123       green
7  123       red
```

I have tried the following but it's not wokring as I'd except

```
duplicated = df['Animals'].duplicated(keep=False) & ~df['Animals'].isna()
dupes = df[duplicated] 
data = df[~duplicated]

dupes.to_csv("Path/DuplicateAnimals.csv", index = False)
data.to_csv("Path/data.csv", index = False)
```

How do I remove both duplicate instances into a new dataframe while ignoring NaN?

Comment: Is the one value `Nan` a typo and should be `NaN`?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35860429/11865956)

Comment: They appear very similar, but OP also wants to split the df into duplicates and uniques, which is not what was asked in the other post.

Comment: Fix Nan, it should be NaN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this to put all duplicates into one dataframe:

```
df1= df[data.groupby('Animals')['Animals'].transform('size') > 1]
df1= df.drop(columns = ['ID',])
```

Then dropped all the duplicates:

```
df2 = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ConsID'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```py
duplicated = df['Animals'].duplicated(keep=False) & ~df['Animals'].isna()
```

Then for `df[~duplicated]` (`df1`) you get:

|  | Animals | Stuff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | nan | blue |
| 4 | nan | 1235 |
| 5 | Dog | 1235 |

And for `df[duplicated]` (`df2`):

|  | Animals | Stuff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Cow | red |
| 2 | 123 | green |
| 3 | Cow | green |
| 6 | 123 | red |

Comment: I just realized the `Nan` didn't copy over correctly as `NaN` to mine either~

Comment: ```[duplicated]``` is taking all the data, and making non-duplicate values NaN. ```[~duplicate]``` is not keeping any NaN, but is removing all duplicates.